# Vanilla javascript ignoring first tab/click

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slide in menu using vanilla javascript for use on phones, but so far all my tests have resulted in the mobile browsers ignoring the first tap (have tried both touchstart & click as events).  Starting with the second tap it works beautifully with each and every subsequent tap.

As opening & closing the menu is the only javascript function on the pages, I don't want to load a huge library, I want to keep it simple and small.  My code is below:

```
var b = document.getElementById('menubtn');
b.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    var n = document.getElementById('nav');
    var ns = n.style.left;
    if (ns == "-600px") {
        n.style.left = "0px";
    } else {
        n.style.left = "-600px";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Any ways to easily eliminate this need for double clicking the first time?

In the fwiw dept, it is a responsive design, with the nav menu in a column on big screens and a slide in on phones.

---

**Edit: Solved the issue**

Following through on Matt Styles comment, I tried using `classList.toggle` and it solved the issue.  The final version is below:

```
var b = document.getElementById('menubtn');
var n = document.getElementById('nav');
b.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
    n.classList.toggle('shwmenu');
    setTimeout(function () {
        b.classList.toggle('shwmenu');
    }, 500);
});
```

I added the delayed menubtn code to toggle the icon between closed and open states.

Comment: This does not directly answer your question so I'll leave it as a comment, but why aren't you using the `touchstart` to toggle a class on and off? [element.classlist.toggle](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) has almost ubiquitous support for touch devices, although if its responsive to work on desktop as well then a click event is probably safer and it is understood everywhere your code will run. Also, your nav element should be outside of your closure, that way you dont query the DOM with each event.

Comment: @MattStyles - I tried the classList.toggle and it works like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you describe could be caused by the following:

In your JS you try to implement some kind of On-Off toggle for your nav element, differentiated on the `left` CSS property value, with `-600` representing the `off` value and `0` representing the `on` value.

As you said, toggling between those states seems to work fine, but what happens when your element is NOT initialized on exactly `-600`? Then on your first tap you will always run into your else clause and set it to `-600` first, showing effectively no visual effect on your first tap, just as you describe.

For an instant test, just swap the if-else clause around to turn it `on` when style.left is not `-600` and then maybe work up towards a more dynamic differentiation between your states ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because `element.style.left` is empty even if you have set `left` property in your stylesheet. You can use element.offsetLeft instead. [Please see here to how it works.](https://jsfiddle.net/L8qqwo68/)

[HTMLElement.style - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

> The style property is not useful for learning about the element's style in general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the `<head>` section, or external style sheets. To get the values of all CSS properties for an element you should use window.getComputedStyle() instead.